# Argument list for class template is missing, but not with VisualC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, variadic-templates, iar

With IAR compiler, I have the following error:
`Argument list for class template "CallbackInterface" is missing`
But with VisualC++, it compiles like a charm.

What could explain it?

Heres is my callback interface

```
template<typename DataModel, typename... ArgumentType>
class CallbackInterface : public DataModel
{
public:
    CallbackInterface() {};
    ~CallbackInterface() {};
    CallbackInterface(ArgumentType... arg) : DataModel(arg...) {};

protected:
    ///Callback methods
    static bool AlwaysDisplayable(DataModel* baseInstance) { return true; };
};
```

Here's my specialization for this interface:

```
template<typename DataModel, typename... ArgumentType>
class ThisCallbackInterface : public CallbackInterface<DataModel, ArgumentType...>
{
public:
    ThisCallbackInterface() {};
    ~ThisCallbackInterface() {};
    ThisCallbackInterface(ArgumentType... arg) : CallbackInterface(arg...) {};
```

And my final child class:

```
using DataType = Something;

struct DataModel 
{
  DataModel(){};
  DataModel(DataType dataArgs){};
};

class Child: public CallbackStore<DataModel>, public ThisCallbackInterface<DataModel,DataType>
{
public:
    Child(DataType dataArgs) : 
        CallbackStore(this),
        ThisCallbackInterface(dataArgs){};
    Child():
        CallbackStore(nullptr),
        ThisCallbackInterface(){};
    ~Child(){};
};
```

Comment: What is IAR? I assume your error is in `ThisCallbackInterface(ArgumentType... arg)` constructor?

Comment: could you develop your idea about the ctor?

Comment: IAR? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers

Comment: Clang requires full template parameters in base construction call, even tho https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name suggests, that it shouldn't be neccesary. Try, what @max66 wrote and see, if it helps.

Comment: it did indeed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe explicating the template parameters of `CallbackInterface` ?

```
  ThisCallbackInterface(ArgumentType... arg)
     : CallbackInterface<DataModel, ArgumentType...>(arg...)
   { } // ..............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @GuillaumeD - sorry; my english is horrible; maybe "expliciting"?

Comment: How should I make the arguments explicit? don't I already do it with ThisCallbackInterface<DataModel,DataType> in the class Child declaration?

Comment: @GuillaumeD - Ad far I know, if you inherit from `foo<type1, type2>`, you have to initialize `foo<type1, type2>`, not `foo`.

Comment: shouldn't it be implicit? because it would mean to rewrite the template arg list  in the constructor which would likely be a source of error.  And it compiles with visual c++. I'll try it. thanks.

Comment: @GuillaumeD - we should see the standard and, for this sort of things, is very complicated (for me, at least); anyway, for clang++ and g++ seems isn't implicit. I see the repetition problem but I don't see a way to avoid it; maybe you can define a `using` type inside the class so you can reduce the only one repetition for every class.